# Correlated Random variables

Tags: correlation, random-variable, matlab

On Matlab I would like to simulate a wireless mobile phone cell, in particular I want to reproduce the effect of shadow fading on the link between two users.

So if I consider a certain 2D map, with some random users distributed along the map, I need to obtain from each user perspective a vector of random variable each on reffered to the path to the other users. All this variables are correlated due to the fact that users that are very close should experience approximately the same attenuation. Think of one transmitter A and two receiver which are very close to each other: fadin from A to RX1 and to RX2 should be very close. This relation can be expressed as an exponential:

```
exp(- d/d0)
```

with d the relative distance between A and RX and d0 a reference distance. So the longer the distance the larger will be the random number.

Another example:  Consider a 30m x 30m area with let’s say 10 person in 10 random positions. For each person I want to generate a vector of 10 random  numbers. Each entry of the vector is a number that is influenced by the  relative distance of that user with the other. For example for user  number 1 the vector will have 0 in the first position because the  distance of user 1 from user 1 is zero. Second entry for example is 0.5  for a distance of 10m and third entry is 0.57 for a distance of 11m.

How can I reproduce this?  I realized a correlation matrix whose elements are exp(-d/d0) with d a matrix of all the distances. Then I used the Cholensky decomposition.But the random realization does not follow the criteria I wanted.